Managing maven version in a multi-module project with pom and zip packaging
I have a multi-module maven project for which I am trying to build specific components from the root level. Some modules are packaged as poms and have sub-modules packaged as zips.
Firstly, I would like to increment the versions for the changed modules and their parents. Then I want to rebuild only those incremented components as that should be all that needs rebuilding.
Let's say I have a pom package package1 which relies on library module1.
I then make a change to library module1 and thus want to trigger a rebuild of module1 but also want to trigger a rebuild of package1. Both module1 and package1's version should go from 1.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.1-SNAPSHOT with other modules in the project staying at 1.0-SNAPSHOT.
When setting the version, I am using
mvn version:set -DnewVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT -pl :module1 -amd

I had hoped that the -amd flag (--also-make-dependents) would automatically increment the version on any of the parent modules.
The current outcome is that module1 is rebuilt under the new version but package1 stays on the existing version with simply the version tag for dependency on module1 being updated to 1.1-SNAPSHOT.
As a result, when I build with the following command
mvn clean deploy -pl :module1 -amd 

module1 is rebuilt and uploaded to nexus as 1.1-SNAPSHOT. However, package1 simply gets a new pom.xml file uploaded to nexus under the existing 1.0-SNAPSHOT folder.
Is this a quirk of having pom packages? I can see a similar question on stack overflow below, but u/asg mentions if the packaging type is pom, then it's a different story.
Does incrementing depending module version should increment parent module version?
How can I effectively force increment parent module versions, so they are rebuilt too when I specify -amd?
My other approach was going to be, use the reactor build and mvn dependency:tree to work out the parent modules and specify them under the -pl flag. Is there an easier way?
FYI, using maven 3.5.0 but will be shortly upgrading to 3.9.6

General concept all modules in a multi module have the same version. Releasing etc. is done all in one go... otherwise you should conside splitting up the multi module build into separate projects...
